# I cannot define my color palette for different groups in ggplot for geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script for 5 particles doing Brownian motion which will NOT output groups by color. I can do this well enough using base R, but I am trying to get a handle on ggplot.

Simple script for 5 individual particles performing 10 Brownian steps (the correctness of the steps is irrelevant) and to which a group factor is attached in tibble col 3:

```
#library(tidyverse) (if needed)


######### Construct string num_points starting from zero and moving -1,0,+1 on each step

num_points <- 10
series <- function (num_points) { cumsum(c(0,replicate(num_points-1,(sample(c(-1,0,+1),1)))) ) }

######### Construct dataset of num_sets groups of random walks. Group ID is in col 'z'

num_particles <- 5
data_set <- function (num_points) {
            q <- NULL
            for (i in 1:num_particles) {q_tem <- tibble(x = series(num_points),y = series(num_points),group=as.factor(i))
                                  q <- bind_rows(q,q_tem)
                                  }
            return(q)
}

z <- data_set(num_points)

group.colors <- c("#333BFF","#CC6600","#9633FF","#E2FF33","#E3DB71")

ggplot(z, aes(x=x,y=y, group = group, fill = group)) +  # Properly adding colors

  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)
```

This prints out all 50 points in all black NOT the colors specified. I want to define my palette.

I have tried numerous examples and the code above is pretty much copied from help sites. But the expected colors are not appearing. In the end I want to do many more particles and much larger samples to be printed with overprinting which I have already figured out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here could be that you're using `fill` in your `aes()` function but you're using `geom_point()`, which doesn't have a `fill` aesthetic. You should use `color` instead of `fill` in your `aes()` function.

Try something like this:

```
ggplot(z, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)
```

Here, `aes(color=group)` tells `ggplot` to color the points based on the `group` variable. `scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)` then maps the levels of group to the colors specified in group.colors.

Feel free to tell me if I could help.

Comment: THANK you. I have used base R for decades but haven't used ggplot2 all that much but it's really time to learn.

Comment: Thanks again...I finished my script showing the paths of 60 drunks taking 1000 random 2D Gaussian steps to model New Year's Eve. Thanks again. Picture here... http://www.nfgarland.ca/drunk60.png